# Flask teardown_request happening before request sent

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I have an issue with the `@app.teardown_request` decorator in Flask.

My code is looking like this

```
@app.teardown_request
def teardown_request(exception):
   print 'teardown'

@app.after_request
def after_request(response):
   print 'after'
   return response

@app.route('/entire', methods=['GET'])
def entire():
   print 'entire'
   return 'This is a text'

@app.route('/chunked', methods=['GET'])
def chunked():
   text = 'This is a text'
   def gen(t):
       print 'chunked'
       for a in t:
            yield a
   return gen(text)
```

And when I go to the `/entire` endpoint, I get

```
 after
 teardown
 entire
```

When I go to the `/chunked` endpoint, I get

```
 chunked
 after
 teardown
```

So when returning the data in a chunky way, the request teardown is actually happening before I am returning any data (nor executing any code generating this data).

The data coming from a sqlalchemy session, I find my self closing the session before doing anything with the query - the behaviour I get is then getting `idle in transaction` all over the place...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Flask destroys the context when the response is returned, not after the generator runs.  Use [`stream_with_context`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.stream_with_context) to keep the context around for the generator.

```
from flask import Response, stream_with_context

return Response(stream_with_context(gen(text)))
```